# Azure Kusto Query Language Count two row values as one

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, kql

A value in my application logs changed a few weeks ago and now when I query the logs, I receive two different values in my count. I'm using Azure Logs for graphing so this is rather painful.

How I can query one row value as the other (or query the two row values together)?

For example
I'm counting the fruit column values ('PinkLadyApple', 'Orange', 'Banana'),
The PinkLadyApple is now a JazzApple and when I count the results for 90 days I receive

```
Name          | Sum  
PinkLadyApple | 100 
JazzApple     | 20 
Orange        | 150 
Banana        | 80
```

I'm looking for a solution that either renames the value in the response to just Apple or the two values can be combined under JazzApple
I will then render the results in a graph.

My query looks like

```
fruits
| where timestamp > ago(90d)
| where fruitname in ('PinkLadyApple', 'Orange', 'Banana')
| summarize FruitCount = sum(OtherColumn) by name
```

Comment: Hi @Samuel Polgar, if the answer below helped, I'll appreciate if you accept it (please see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top) to know why and how). Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Samuel Polgar, if the answer below helped, I'll appreciate if you accept it (please see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top) to know why and how). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the old value to the new one, using the `iff()` function, like this:

```
fruits
| where timestamp > ago(90d)
| where fruitname in ('JazzApple', 'PinkLadyApple', 'Orange', 'Banana')
| extend fruitname = iff(fruitname == 'JazzApple', 'PinkLadyApple', fruitname)
| summarize FruitCount = sum(OtherColumn) by name
```

Note that for best performance, I filter for the old and new value (which uses indexes), and only then changing the old value to the new one, just before the `summarize` operator.

And if you have multiple renamed values, then you can use the `case()` function instead, like this:

```
fruits
| where timestamp > ago(90d)
| where fruitname in ('JazzApple', 'PinkLadyApple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'OldValue2', 'OldValue3')
| extend fruitname = case(
   fruitname == 'JazzApple', 'PinkLadyApple',
   fruitname == 'OldValue2', 'NewValue2',
   fruitname == 'OldValue3', 'NewValue3',
   fruitname)
| summarize FruitCount = sum(OtherColumn) by name
```